# How do meet a specific criteria for column in panda data frame as well as checking whether the value is more than equal to 10,000

Tags: python, pandas

Hello am doing my assignment and I have encountered a question that I can't answer. The question is to create another DataFrame df_urban consisting of all columns of the original dataset but comprising of only applicants with Urban status in their Property_Area attribute (exclude Rural and Semiurban) with ApplicantIncome of at least S$10,000. Reset the row index and display the last 10 rows of this DataFrame.

[Picture of the question](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bdYJr.png)

My code however will not meet the criteria of Applicant Income of at least 10,000 as well as only urban status in the area.

df_urban = df
df_urban.iloc[-10:[11]]

I Was wondering what is the solution to the question.
[Data picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8xGxG.png)

Answer (score 0):

you can use the '&' operator to limit the data by multiple column conditions:

```
df_urban = df[(df[col]==<condition>) & (df[col] >= <condition>)]
```

Answer (score 0):

Following is a simple code snippet performing a proof of principle in extracting a subset of the primary data frame to produce a subset data frame of only "Urban" locations:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_csv('Applicants.csv',delimiter='\t')

print(df)

df_urban = df[(df['Property_Area'] == 'Urban')]

print(df_urban)
```

Using a simply built CSV file, here is a sample of the output:

```
       ApplicantIncome  CoapplicantIncome  LoanAmount  Loan_Term  Credit_History Property_Area
0             4583               1508      128000        360               1         Rural
1             1222                  0       55000        360               1         Rural
2             8285                  0       64000        360               1         Urban
3             3988               1144       75000        360               1         Rural
4             2588                  0       84700        360               1         Urban
5             5248                  0       48550        360               1         Rural
6             7488                  0      111000        360               1     SemiUrban
7             3252               1112       14550        360               1         Rural
8             1668                  0       67500        360               1         Urban
   ApplicantIncome  CoapplicantIncome  LoanAmount  Loan_Term  Credit_History Property_Area
2             8285                  0       64000        360               1         Urban
4             2588                  0       84700        360               1         Urban
8             1668                  0       67500        360               1         Urban
```

Answer (score 0):

See below. I leave it to you to work out how to reset index. You might want to look at .tail() to display last rows.

```
df_urban = df[(df['ApplicantIncome'] > 10000) & (df['Property_Area'] == 'Urban')]
```

Comment: i believe it should be '>=' as the criteria states "at least"

Comment: Thanks, you are of course correct. Like in your useful answer, I wanted to give a good lead without actually doing the whole assignment but did not notice the 'at least'.